# How can I upgrade my PHP 5.3.1 to 5.3.2 on XAMPP Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've just installed XAMPP on Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and everything is running correctly and setup completely well.

However, I want to install an open source project that requires PHP 5.3.2 or higher. I visited the official PHP website and downloaded PHP 5.4.5.

How can I update my PHP version so that it runs with this latest version?

I visited:

> Places -> Application -> XAMPP -> xamppfiles -> ???

I'd appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you get any where with the solution ?

Comment: What about `brew`? E.g. `brew install php`?

Answer (score 1):

Not to lead you in a different direction, but if you were using MAMP (free version) on OS X, that comes with the most up-to-date version of PHP and allows to you switch between 5.2.17 & 5.4.3.

I find that MAMP is less messy than XAMPP.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm aware of MAMP, Macports, Brew, etc. I'm asking specifically about XAMPP. :P

Comment: no worries, I do hope you dont spend too much time trying to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest binary version of PHP 5.3.2 (make sure to get the .zip package not the installer)

De-archive it to a directory

Copy the contents of the directory in the php subfolder of your XAMPP installation directory, overwriting the files which are already present
Overwrite the files which are already present in the apache\bin directory with the newer versions.

Now the trick: take the files which have a "_2" in their names (for example php5apache2_2.dll or php5apache2_2_filter.dll), copy them in the apache\bin subdirectory and remove the "_2" part, overwriting the existing files. This is necessary because by XAMPP uses Apache version 2.2 and the files with the 2 prefix are built for Apache 2.0, so you must take the files build for the newer version (which has a different plugin interface) and rename them in the filenames XAMPP expects.

Comment: The question is for Mac not Windows!